# How to use ashx for html image defined in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I have an issue with ashx handler for showing image when i defined HTMl image in code behind. IF i define in ascx, the image is pulled fine but not if i define in .cs.

This is the way i

```
 HtmlImage img1 = new HtmlImage();
 img1.Src = "imageout.ashx?PageID=" + PageID.ToString() + "&DIImageID=" + DIImageID.ToString();
```

In the place of the image, it displays the text of src "imageout.ashx?......."

What is it i am missing here? Help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
img1.Attributes["src"] = "imageout.ashx?PageID=" + PageID.ToString() + "&DIImageID=" + DIImageID.ToString();
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
img1.Src = ResolveClientUrl(string.Format("~/imageout.ashx?PageID={0}&DIImageID={1}", PageID, DIImageID));
```

The trick is in the ResolveClientUrl method call. String.Format method has utilized just for increase readability.

For use in user control:

```
 img1.Src = ResolveUrl(string.Format("~/imageout.ashx?PageID={0}&DIImageID={1}", PageID, DIImageID));
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but unfortunately, it shows the same url in the place of image. Any other idea, please?